# reverting a commit in svn, merge does not seem to do anything

Tags: svn, version-control

the consensus on reverting a SVN commit seems to be:

```
svn merge -c -492 svn+ssh://...../trunk/
svn status
svn commit -m "i'm a moron. reverting to rev X"
```

So, right now I was typing my commit message and a bad copy paste carried a new line... i ctrl+C right away, but alas, i have all my garbage in trunk.

from rev 491 to 492 there was about 10 files modified (4 were intended)

after `merge -c -1` or either `merge -r 492:491`, i get nothing changed in my working copy.

`svn status` says everything is up to date, and there's nothing to comit.

```
svn up
> at revision 492
svn merge -c -492 ... #or -2 ... or -r 492:491
> return code 0
svn st
> nothing changed...
```

what am I doing wrong?

--
edit 1:

I checked out the working copy trunk at another directory and it works
after `svn merge -c -1 svn+ssh://...` i get the U and D status change listed and i'm back to 491, and i can commit

back to the trouble directory, even after cleaning and `revert -R` that merge command gives me nothing. I really want to understand why.

--
edit 2:

fixed the -c syntax thanks to @slowdog

-- 
edit 3:

svn version 1.6.17 (r1128011)

Comment: "svn merge -c -1" means "reverse-merge revision 1". What you want here is "svn merge -c -492". But that's equivalent to "-r 492:491".

Comment: You should not need to specify a URL to back out a commit you just made from the same working copy. Maybe you're giving the wrong URL? Does "svn merge -c -492 ." work better?

Comment: @slowdog `$svn merge -c  -1` svn: Merge source required, same for `-c -492`

Comment: The full command needed is `svn merge -c -492 .` (the final `.` is the "merge source" and destination)

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn update -rHEAD` and then try again.

Comment: `svn update` defaults to `-r HEAD`, but i tried, and same thing happened.